# INstallation problem acer 5050

Tags: system-installation

My acer 5050 doesn't reboot with ubuntu after the cd's installation. It continues with the windows xp. Do I have to restart always with the CD in the unit? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu next to windows you should remove the installation disk and restart. Normally this automaticly boots Ubuntu after waiting a few seconds but in the boot menu you should be able to select either windows or ubuntu. Be carefull not to select the wrong windows because that way you will delete everything and will be left with a clean windows install.